# Indexing with tuples in Python

Tags: python, tuples

Here is my input:

```
print(type(location))
print(location)
```

Here is my output:

```
<class 'tuple'>
(2, 1)
<class 'tuple'>
(1, 2)
<class 'tuple'>
(1, 0)
<class 'tuple'>
(3, 1)
<class 'tuple'>
(2, 0)
```

I am trying to implement a Manhattan distance function where I can use abs(x1-x2) + abs(y1-y2). (I am referencing each tuple as (x,y).) I tried to be able to break up the tuples using the following code:

```
location[0][0]
```

Where I hoped to get an output of 2, but I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I am able to use this:

```
location[0]
```

And I get this output:

```
2
1
1
3
2
```

But this is not helping me to break up the tuple or be able to implement the Manhattan distance function. Is there any way I can reference specific 'x' and 'y' values within the tuple?

Comment: what is `a`? how does it relate to `location`?

Comment: I misnamed it, but I fixed it now

Comment: so `location[0]` is an integer so it doesn't have an index

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking... If you have `a=(1,2)`, then `a[0]` is 1 and `a[1]` is 2... `a[0][0]` first gets the 1, and then tries to index into *that* which, of course, causes an error.

Comment: You have one dimensional data structure it means, if location = (1,2) location[0] =  1 and location[1] = 2

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have structured your tuple `location` incorrectly. Your tuple is single-dimensional. You need to make it double-dimensional and then apply your function. Here is an example code:

```py
location = ((2, 1), (1, 2), (1, 0), (3, 1), (2, 0))
def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return abs(x1-x2) + abs(y1-y2)

print(distance(location[0][0], location[0][1], location[1][0], location[1][1]))
```

Or here is a more cleaned-up version:

```py
location = ((2, 1), (1, 2), (1, 0), (3, 1), (2, 0))
def distance(point1, point2):
    return abs(point1[0]-point2[0]) + abs(point1[1]-point2[1])

print(distance(location[0], location[1]))
```

Hope this is what you needed